# Connect Azure Logic App to multiple storage accounts

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

My logic app in *Microsoft azure* is connected to 1 storage account (pre-production), I want to connect it also to a second storage account (production). I need to use the new connection for the activity *create blob (v2)*.

[image]

How do I create an endpoint from the side of storage account and how to register it correct in logic app?

When I enter existing blob endpoint I still get connectivity error, I don't get directly access in folder path input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you just have to click change connection like below:

[image]

and then add new connection for that action :

[image]

Then the connection has changed like below:

[image]

> How do I create an endpoint from the side of storage account and how to register it correct in logic app?

Firstly, you need to on managed identity in logic app:

[image]

Then go to storage account, then access control(IAM), then add role assignment, then select storage blob data contributor role and then select members in that logic app identity need to selected like below:

[image]

then:

[image]

Then it will added like below and now your logic app can access the storage account.

[image]